# SF Short Story: Humans are attempting to join the Galactic Federation

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

Humans are attempting to join the Galactic Federation.
A small team are sent to represent Humanity and prove our worth to the aliens.

When it looks as if our membership is to be rejected the chief ambassador activates a FTL communications system embedded behind his ear.

He discusses the situation with Earth. It turns out that this is a ruse and the Humans know that they would be overheard, thus proving the existence of the FTL system and therefore increasing Humanities worthiness of membership.

The final word is between an Alien and his home world via a REAL FTL comms link to his HQ.

The Alien concludes the conversation stating that Humanity had been allowed to join so that they can keep a closer eye on us as no other species had been so duplicitous in their application.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/123230/humans-fake-ftl-communication-story-identification

Comment: @Andrew I think you're correct, but neither of the potential previous duplicates has an accepted answer.  If you want to put one together I'd vote it up.

Comment: It was indeed 'Conviction' by Brian Aldiss, I have since found it in the anthology Space time & Nathaniel. It had been decades since I last read it and I had a few things distorted. When I posed the question I was presented with a list of similar previous questions, none of which matched. Andrew, what was the technique that led you to find the existing duplicates? I think that SamW was the first to offer a tentative answer in 2013. But each of the three questions had parts of the story wrong. I cannot judge whose answer should count.

Comment: I remembered some questions about "fake FTL" and searched for that.  Glad I was able to help you find your story

Comment: @Seldon2k One of the advantages those of us who have been active here longer have is that there's a fair chance we've stumbled across those existing answers before from our own searching or reading.  It's not a slight on you at all; searching can be hard unless you happen to recall some exact term from the post you're looking for, and everybody phrases things differently.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think this is "[Conviction](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?51080)" by Brian Aldiss (as similar questions have been answered), available [here](https://archive.org/details/New_Worlds_051v17_1956-09/page/n45/mode/2up)

**Humans are attempting to join the Galactic Federation. A small team are sent to represent Humanity and prove our worth to the aliens.**

> The four Supreme Ultralords stood apart from the crowd, waiting,
> speaking to nobody. Yet Mordregon, son of Great Mordregon ; Arntibis
> Isis of Sirius III, the Proctor Superior from the Tenth Sector; Deln
> Phi J. Bunswacki, Ruler of the Margins; and Ped 2 of the Dominion of
> the Sack watched, as did the countless other members of the Diet of
> the Ultralords of the Home Galaxy, the entrance into their council
> chamber of the alien, **David Stevens of Earth**.

**When it looks as if our membership is to be rejected the chief ambassador activates a FTL communications system embedded behind his ear.**

> Catching sight of the dazed look on the Earthman’s face, Ped 2 could
> not resist driving home another point. (His was a childish race :
> theologians had died out among them only some four thousand years
> ago).
>
> “We are not even talking to you in a sense you would understand, David
> Stevens of Earth,” he said. “Having as yet no instantaneous
> communicator across light year distances, we are letting a robot brain
> on Xaquibadd do the talking for us. We can check with it afterwards;
> if a mistake has been made, we can always get in touch with you.”
>
> It was said not with an easy menace, but Stevens received at least a
> part of it eagerly. They had as yet no instantaneous communicator! No
> sub-radio that could leap light years without time lag!
> Involuntarily, he again fingered the tiny lump beneath the lobe of his
> right ear, and then thrust his hand deep into his pocket. So Earth had
> a chance of bargaining with these colossi after all ! His confidence
> soared.

---

> The silence grew round him like ice forming over a Siberian lake. Were
> they hostile or not? He could not tell anything from their attitude ;
> he could not think objectively. Reverse that idea: ‘ he thought
> subjectively.’ Could he twist that into some sort of a weird virtue
> which might appeal to them, and pretend there was a special value in
> thinking subjectively ?
>
> Hell, this was not his line of reasoning at all; he was not cut out
> to be a metaphysician. It was time he played his trump card. With an
> almost imperceptible movement of a neck muscle, he switched on the
> little machine in his throat. Immediately its droning awoke,
> reassuring him.
>
> “I must have a moment to think,” Stevens said to the assembly.
>
> Without moving his lips, he whispered, **‘Hello, Earth, are you there.
> Earth? Dave Stevens calling across the light-years. Do you hear me?
> ’**
>
> After a moment’s pause, the tiny lump behind his ear throbbed and a
> shadowy voice answered, ‘Hello, Stevens, Earth Centre here. We’ve
> been listening out for you. How are you doing ?’
>
> ‘The trial is on. I don’t think I’m making out very well.’ His lips
> were moving slightly; he covered them with his hand, standing as if
> deep in cogitation. It looked, he thought, very suspicious. He went
> on, ‘I can’t say much. For one thing, Fm afraid they will detect this
> beam going out and regard our communication as infringing their
> judicial regulations.’

---

> **“ So that little bit of recording we fixed up behind your ugly great
> ear did the trick?”**
>
> “ It sounded so absolutely genuine I almost believed it was the real
> thing,” Stevens said enthusiastically. “ I’m convinced we’ve won the
> day with that gadget.”

**The final word is between an Alien and his home world via a REAL FTL comms link to his HQ.
The Alien concludes the conversation stating that Humanity had been allowed to join so that they can keep a closer eye on us as no other species had been so duplicitous in their application.**

> Our Council of the Ultralords must be certain it pronounces the
> correct verdict when aliens such as Stevens are under examination ;
> consequently, it has to have telepaths present during the trials. All
> it asks is, simply, integrity in the defendants — that is the simple
> touchstone : yet it is too difficult for many of them. **The men of
> Earth tortured themselves chasing phantoms, cooking up chimeras.**
> Stevens had integrity, yet would not trust to it. Those who are
> convicted of dishonesty perish ; we have no room for them.
>
> The robot craft swung away from Luna and headed at full speed towards
> Earth, the motors in its warhead ticking expectantly, counting out the
> seconds to annihilation.
>
> And that, of course, would be the end of the story — for Earth at
> least. **It would have been completely destroyed as is usual in such
> distressing cases, but Mordregon, who was amused by Stevens’ bluff,
> decided that, after all, the warped brains of Earthmen might be useful
> in coping with the warped brains of the enemy Eleventh Galaxy. He
> called it ‘ an expedient war-time measure.’**
>
> Quietly, he deflected the speeding missile from its target, ordering
> it to return home. **He sent this message by sub-radio, of course ;
> dangerous aliens must necessarily be deluded at times.**